# Gigolo under fedora 12 xfce

Tags: permissions, fedora, xubuntu, xfce

I installed fedora 12 xfce

and when i run Gigolo to mount windows partitions i get Authentication is required.

In fedora 11 xfce there was a tool that change the system permission to allow any

user to mount any partition,but i cant find it in fedora 12.

please help me how to fix this problem and set all the permission needed for any other application.

Comment: belongs to superuser.com

Comment: Sorry i think that this is not the correct place for my question.

Comment: This problem is also occuring in xubuntu 9.10, perhaps other systems as well.

Comment: im sorry i couldn't stop laughing when i saw the title of this question.

Answer (score 0):

After reading from the Gigolo Help (http://www.uvena.de/gigolo/help.html), trying to install the [gnome-mount wrapper script for exo-mount](http://wiki.xfce.org/gnomemount-replacement), trying gnome-mount utility with `apt-get`, trying to update my *~/.local/share/applications/defaults.list*, trying to add my user account to the fuse group, and trying various combinations of the above elements, I finally found something that worked.

I installed and ran [ntfs-config](http://flomertens.free.fr/ntfs-config/index.html). On my Xubuntu 9.10 installation, I achieved this with the following commands:

$ sudo apt-get install ntfs-config
$ gksudo ntfs-config

So far, it is working. I'm not sure what ntfs-config does, but unfortunately I don't have the time right now to find out. I would welcome additional info about the utility.